# Help with a translation into Classical Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

How would I say the phrase "Retaliate with Success" in classical Latin?

Comment: Welcome to the site! We have a specialy policy here for translation requests: they should include what you have tried your self, if at all possible. They should also include maximum context: what is it for? Can you explain the message it is supposed to convey? Etc.

Answer (score 2):

*Prospere* seems a good word for 'with success'. For an example, I immediately thought of 'prospere, procede, et regna' from the Psalms (though granted, that's ecclesiastical.

For retalitate, I rescind my previous answer of punire - instead I propose ulcisci, which my Lewis and Short marks as common in classical usage, as in “odi hominem et odero: utinam ulcisci possem! sed illum ulciscentur mores sui,” Cic. Att. 9, 12, 2.

Thus, I have Prospere Ulciscimini or Prospere Ulciscere, depending on the number.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This looks like a promising option. Can you explain or discuss your choice of words a little? I don't immediately see how those verbs work for "retaliate", but it's probably because they have a nuance I don't know or remember. (Answers always get much more value from explanation in addition to mere statement.)

Comment: Thank you!  I have edited my answer.

Comment: Excellent! I'd vote up a second time if I could.